# What is the value of "exp" in a SUBSCRIPTION_CANCELED postback?

Tags: android-pay

I am trying to establish until when (if at all - is the final payment prorated?) a user's subscription should persist beyond a cancellation.

Is the value in the "exp" field from [the postback JSON](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/subscriptions#6) the time at which the cancellation occurred, or the time until which their subscription benefits should persist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exp` is defined in the [JWT spec](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token.html#expDef). It refers to when the JWT should be treated as "expired" (e.g. to reject the JWT in its entirety because it's "outdated").

As defined in that link you get the cancellation postback whenever Google can't obtain payment - I'd  **interpret** (defer to official Google support on this) that as being either the initial and/or renewal payment (because the user cancelled or some other reason - maybe expired card?).

If I'm not mistaken, the current frequency is only monthly, and the "prorated" value is something you [define for initial payment](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/jsreference#sub). So you actually define what that initial payment is - a prorated value (e.g. first x days of subscription) or some initial fee and can make the "decision" on what a failed payment/cancellation postback means to you...